# Jquery detach and reattach to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move from 1 table row to another table row with `jquery`.
The row was detach but was not reattach to another table.
I have the same columns and format across all tables.

```
function copyToTableTwo(id) {
  var det=$('#del' + id).detach()
  $("#del" + id).appendTo("#table2");
}

function CopyToTableThree(id) {
   $('#del' + id).detach()
   $("#del" + id).appendTo("#table3");
}
```

**html markup**

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            col 1
        </th>
        <th>
            col 2
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="delMyID">
        <td>my row content</td>
        <td>my row content</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning delbtn" onclick="copyToTableTwo('#delMyID')" name="name" value="detach TO next Table" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Typo in `copyToTableTwp`

Comment: hi sorry. i mean i am trying to shift entire row to another table including the IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions would need to be global to be accessible from within an inline `onclick` attribute, but assuming they are then I believe the problem is that when you call the function:

```
onclick="copyToTableTwo('#delMyID')"
```

...you pass the selector `'#delMyID'`, then within the function you take that value and prepend `'#del'` to it:

```
$('#del' + id)
```

So you're trying to select `$('#del#delMyID')`, which of course doesn't match any elements.

Just use the `id` argument on its own:

```
$(id).appendTo("#table2");
```

Note that you don't need to call `.detach()` at all, because the `.appendTo()` method will move the element.

In context:

```js
function copyToTableTwo(id) {
  $(id).appendTo("#table2");
}
```

```css
table { border: thin black solid; margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="table1">
  <tr><th>col 1</th><th>col 2</th></tr>
  <tr id="delMyID">
    <td>my row content</td>
    <td>my row content</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" onclick="copyToTableTwo('#delMyID')" name="name" value="detach TO next Table" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="table2">
  <tr><td>This is</td><td>Table 2</td>
</table>
```

Comment: hi appendTo works .i always thought append is only append and now i know it will detach also. Thanks buddy

Comment: If you specify multiple targets (e.g., `.appendTo(".someClassThatMatchesMultipleElements")` then it will make copies and append to all of those targets. If the target is a single element it moves it.

Comment: i see. Now i know something new about appenTo